# Java: Method statements executing out of order

Tags: java, android

I have this method where I execute 2 queries to put data into 2 Lists, after that, I want to validate the size of the lists (for debugging purposes).

The Method:

```
postList = new ArrayList<>();
    Query query = postRef.orderByChild("timestamp");
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            int k = 0;
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                postList.add(ds.getValue(Post.class));
                Log.d("Display All Posts", postList.get(k).getTime());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    followingList = new ArrayList<>();
    userRef.child(userId).child("following").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            int k = 0;
            for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Log.d("Following",  "New user found:" + ds.getValue());
                followingList.add(ds.getValue(String.class));
                Log.d("FollowingList value", followingList.get(k));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    Log.d("b1 and b2 ", "this is happening");
    Log.d("Post Size", String.valueOf(postList.size()));
    Log.d("following size", String.valueOf(followingList.size()));
}
```

I Know for sure that the code in the Red box is happening first, followed by the query pointed by the green arrow and lastly the query pointed by the yellow line.

[image: I Know for sure that the code in the Red box is happening first, followed by the query pointed by the green arrow and lastly the query pointed by the yellow line.]

**Question**

How do I make the instruction in the box execute last?

PS: I've tried putting it in another method and then call the method, same result.

Comment: call log code inside addListenerForSingleValueEvent method.

Comment: You would have to wait for `onDataChange` to be called before proceeding, for example using a `CountDownLatch`. Or, easier, put that code inside the `onDataChange` method.

Comment: The yellow arrow points to call back functions. It's executed whenever a value changed. So you have to place your red box code inside that call back to be executed last

Comment: Green and Yellow part are asynchronous events.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is behaving as expected. `ValueEventListener.onDataChange` is an asynchronous call which will be executed at some other point of time. It will be not be executed sequentially as you are expecting as a result your logs are getting printed first. Move those Logs in `onDataChange` to ensure its executed as per your need.